# error: server side activities have been updated you need to restart sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have installed VS 2017 with SharePoint Designer 2013 32 bit and when i configure workflow manager, i get this error: server side activities have been updated you need to restart sharepoint designer.

Most of the blogs suggested to uninstall Workflow manager client from Control panel - Programs , but i didnt see it listed there but when i open Web platform installer, i see it installed on my machine.

Comment: Clear the cache folders  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/

Comment: i did but it didnt work.

Comment: try to uninstall SharePoint Designer 2013 32 and install SharePoint Designer 2013 64 bit

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Symon's approach didn't help me. So here's what I followed and it resolved the issue.
Clear cache from below locations

1. %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
2. %APPDATA%\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache
3. %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
4. %APPDATA%\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer

•   Now uninstall SharePoint Designer
•   Reboot and then re-install in below order.

Order of installation

1. SharePoint Designer 64-bit ([sharepointdesigner2013_64bit.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35491)) File Version: 15.0.4420.1017
2. SharePoint Designer Service Pack 1 ([spdsp2013-kb2817441-fullfile-x64-en-us.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42009)) File Version: 15.0.4569.1506
3. Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 ([spd2013-kb2863836-fullfile-x64-glb.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42871)) File Version: 15.0.4615.1001
4. Update for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 ([spd2013-kb3114337-fullfile-x64-glb.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/january-12-2016-update-for-sharepoint-designer-2013-kb3114337-68360e75-0a58-989d-ca58-cacc91a578f7)) File Version: 15.0.4787.1000. This update is included in windows update as it is classified as critical. Check the link for more details and stand alone package
5. Update for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 ([spd2013-kb3114721-fullfile-x64-glb.exe](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53389)) File Version: 15.0.4849.1000

Comment: this worked for me. this should have been marked as the answer.

Comment: Work for me as well. I should add that I was unable to uninstall SharePoint Designer 2013 because the setup file was missing. I tried uninstalling using the Easy Fix tool from Microsoft but that did not remove the application from the control panel. Cleaning the registry with CCleaner resolved that part.

Comment: Service Pack did not installed for me. I had to force install: 
`spdsp2013-kb2817441-fullfile-x86-en-us.exe PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1`

Comment: We are getting error on update 4. Can you update the link?

Comment: The only thing that was needed in my case was the installation of SP 1 and then installation of KBKB3114337 and then clearing the caches. I didnt have to uninstall and reinstall everything you have listed. But your solution was very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I delete all the mentioned folders from above and nothing is working now.. Central admin nothing is working now :( everthing is gone

Comment: Here in 2020 November, Followed the step. File in 4 the steps seems to be missing, but going through the other files, it worked fine! Thanks for the links

Comment: Here in 2022.  Followed these steps, and ta-da!  Thank you so much.

Comment: @MurtuzaHusain link updated.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the January 12, 2016, update for SharePoint Designer 2013 (**KB3114337**). it fixes that issue:

*When you try to create a SharePoint 2013 workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 on a computer that has Microsoft.Activities.dll installed, you receive the following error message:
Server-side activities have been updated. You need to restart SharePoint Designer to use the updated version of activities.*

Before installing this package you must first install the prerequisite **Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 Service Pack 1**.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114337/january-12--2016--update-for-sharepoint-designer-2013-kb3114337

Comment: I am also having the same issue and I followed above steps still issue is not resolved.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, except that I also had to clear the caches as listed in the other solution by Bulli. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Have tried to download all MS update files and SP1, what eventually worked to not have the "server-side..." erro was

- Uninstall Visual Studio
- Open the site I need access to in SPD on IE11 first (must be IE11 if work security is authenticated through IE11 as main), then open the site in SPD, and the workflow was able to download through web service onto local cache

Comment: Opening the site in Internet Explorer 11 (IE) solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

Removing Visual Studio 2017 resolved the issue for me using SharePoint Designer (32 bit).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Removing Visual studio 2017 from system resolved the issue.

Comment: Worked for me. I installed vs 2005 and the extension, tried clearning cache forlders, reinstalled the 64bit version, installed all the sp1 and other packages, on WIndows 10. And uninstalled VS 2017 and then worked at last. (I do have VS 2019).

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your SharePoint designer.

1 Install Microsoft sharepoint designer service pack

2 install the update for the sharepoint designer

You can found solution of this from here, [SP designer 2013 error](http://www.techrobbers.com/2019/03/sharepoint-designer-workflow-error.html)

Answer (score 0):

Bulli's way worked for me.

Usually i'd manage the sites with the SharePoint Admin accounts while logged in as my own,I'd tried running SPD as a different user but it didn't work because one of the troubleshooting steps affects the current logged in user which was then my own : %USERPROFILE%

It may be faster to temporarily add your current logged in user as the site collection administrator to edit workflows through SPD if you'd applied the suggested fixes under your own account.