# Cannot create SPD 2013 Workflow on SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint online team site. I am owner of the site and office 365 too. When I tried to create a 2010 Workflow using SPD, it gets created. But I am unable to create a 2013 Workflow. I am getting the following screen while creating 2013 workflow:

[image]

I searched over internet for solutions to solve this problem and I have tried everything mentioned in [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218892/error-server-side-activities-have-been-updated-you-need-to-restart-sharepoint-d) post to no effect.

Can someone **please** give me a solution to this problem?

**Note:** Please don't mark the post as duplicate because the other post (link mentioned above) did not solve the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it a modern site like communication or team site ?

Comment: Its a Team site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: server side activities have been updated you need to restart sharepoint designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218892/error-server-side-activities-have-been-updated-you-need-to-restart-sharepoint-d)

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate, take a look here and follow the steps BY THE BOOK (the answer with a lot of links). I had the same problem -> https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218892/error-server-side-activities-have-been-updated-you-need-to-restart-sharepoint-d

Comment: Have you read the question properly? I mentioned I have tried everything to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was VS2017. I uninstalled it and then the workflow worked. But I need both VS2017 as well as SPD13. So, after trying everything mentioned in older posts to no effect, I uninstalled VS2017 and SharePoint Designer 2013 (64-bit) completely.

Then I first installed Designer and its January Update and then I installed VS2017 which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the [January 12, 2016, update for SharePoint Designer 2013 (KB3114337)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3114337/january-12-2016-update-for-sharepoint-designer-2013-kb3114337). it fixes that issue:

*When you try to create a SharePoint 2013 workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013 on a computer that has Microsoft.Activities.dll installed, you receive the following error message: Server-side activities have been updated. You need to restart SharePoint Designer to use the updated version of activities.*

Before installing this package, you must first install the prerequisite Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 Service Pack 1.

Comment: I have tried that already to no effect!

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

Navigate to Site settings.
Select 'Workflow settings'.
Select '(Workflow Health)'. (This is actually a link)
On the Workflow Health page, click on the 'Activate' next to the Workflow Service Store feature.

Restart sharepoint designer

You should now be able to see sharepoint 2013 workflows